# How can i get friend's friends list of facebook api in c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want get **friend's friends list** of Facebook API.

I can get my friend list, but I can't get friends friends list of Facebook API with c#.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: i so try to fined my answer , i try with fb api and another . but i cant find any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible to get List of Friends of a friend but **only condition** is that friend should be user of that application.

Suppose there is an application "APP" used by "A" then the APP can get his friends List , now you want friends List of "B" who is friend of "A" , it will be possible only if "B" also uses the "APP"

**Also try your hands on code and show us from code for the same**

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you **cannot** fetch that!

The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) don't provide any API to do so.